# can't open a file by reading its name from another file in c++

Tags: c++, stdin, freopen

Hi I am trying to read a file name from another file and then read it. But I can only read the first file which contains the name of the second file I want to open. Here is how I am doing it..

```
int main()
{
freopen("input1.txt","r",stdin);
while(cin>>fileName>>source>>destination)
{
    //reads perfectly
    char file[100];

    for(int i=0;i<(int)fileName.size();i++)
        file[i] = fileName[i];

    file[(int)fileName.size()] = NULL;        

    freopen(file,"r",stdin);

    mp.clear();
    mp1.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<cityNumber;i++)
        adj[i].clear();
    cityNumber = 0;

    while(cin>>city1>>city2>>distanc)
    {
       //doesn't read
    }
}
```

Comment: Am i the only one who doesn't know what *mp.clear();mp1.clear();* are doing?

Comment: I know I should have deleted them before posting! But its obvious they don't have anything to do with taking input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code uses overly complicated constructs. Why not just do it the straightforward C++ way:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
std::ifstream input1("input1.txt");
while(input1 >> fileName >> source >> destination)
{
    std::ifstream file(fileName.c_str());

    mp.clear();
    mp1.clear();

    for(int i=0;i<cityNumber;i++)
        adj[i].clear();
    cityNumber = 0;

    while(file >> city1 >> city2 >> distanc)
    {
       //work with values
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes yours are much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: But it shows an error 
 `variable 'std::ifstream input1' has initializer but incomplete type`

Comment: @kalkin I've edited the answer to include the necessary header.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `freopen` says:

> The `freopen()` function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by `path` and associates the stream pointed to by stream with it. The original  stream  (if  it exists) is closed.

Hence,

```
freopen("input1.txt","r",stdin);
```

closes the `stdin` stream, and

```
freopen(file,"r",stdin);
```

finds no open stream to associate to `file`.

You should probably plain `fopen` the file `input.txt` and read from it to leave `stdin` for the final target.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to consider:

- do not use freopen/fopen family of files in C++ (unless it's a really special case)
- do not mix std::iostreams with fopen family of files (freopen should not be used here)

  these two points will fix your particular error (as @Angew pointed out)
- prefer `std::string` with `std::getline` instead of `char file[100];` This avoids buffer overflow if reading over 100 chars (I believe you don't check for errors) and simplifies your code.
- prefer iterators over iterating by index.

That means instead of:

```
for(int i=0;i < cityNumber;i++)
    adj[i].clear();
```

you could/should write:

```
// C++11
for(auto& city: adj)
    city.clear();

// C++98
for(<type of adj>::iterator city = adj.begin(); city != adj.end(); ++city)
    city->clear();
```